# Tensorflow Iterator error Out of range: End of sequence, when initializing global variables

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I have a piece of tensorflow code that is failing for a very confusing reason. When I create an iterator, it creates normally and functions well, calling iterator.get_next() works perfectly and returns what I need it to.
However, when it comes time to initialize all other variables the iterator breaks.
From this code:

```
    print("checking iterator before run", model.iterator)
    sess.run(model.iterator.initializer)
    print("finished initializing the iterator")
    try:
        print("\n in progressive iterator has next", model.iterator.get_next())
    except:
        print("\n iterator doesn't have a next\n")
    sess.run(tf.compat.v1.global_variables_initializer())
    print("finished initializing all variables")
```

I get this output:

> checking iterator before run
> <tensorflow.python.data.ops.iterator_ops.Iterator object at
> 0x7fd75a7f9f90> finished initializing the iterator
>
> in progressive iterator has next (<tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:0'
> shape=(7, 512, 512, 3) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:1'
> shape=(7, 256, 256, 3) dtype=float32>)
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- OutOfRangeError                           Traceback (most recent call
> last)

I will copy the most important parts of the traceback here:

> OutOfRangeError: 2 root error(s) found.
> (0) Out of range: End of sequence
> [[node Inputs/inputs (defined at /somefile.py:104) ]]
> [[Inputs/inputs/_1]]
> (1) Out of range: End of sequence
> [[node Inputs/inputs (defined at /somefile.py:104) ]]

Where somefile line 104 is where I define the iterator, and the traceback leads me to this line where the error is caused:

> return self.iterator.get_next(name='inputs')

Which is called when defining the iterator, but we define it long before the print statements that successfully print are called, so that line seems to run successfully.
What is it about sess.run(tf.compat.v1.global_variables_initializer()), that causes this error? Has anyone seen this issue before?